# Moving from nss to openssl on plesk

Tags: ssl, paypal, openssl, plesk, nss

I'm using paypal php sdk and I get an error:

```
Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1
```

Searching on google I found that the error is occurred because the server is running nss (that doesn't support tlsv1) instead of openssl. How can I switch from nss to openssl? I also have plesk installed on my server if it could be a problem

Comment: Is there chance that you mistakenly add protocol name "TLSv1" into cipher list?

Comment: No, how can I do it?

Comment: Ok, in there anything about nss in "php -i" output? Have you even have any of libcurl nss packages installed?

Comment: Yes doing php -i I see that curl uses nss package. Searching online I found that nss does not support tlsv1; for this reason I would move to openssl (doing php -i it says that openssl is supported)

Comment: I'm afraid that if your exact php was build with nss it will be impossible to use openssl in it. But as you have Plesk you can install any of php provided by Plesk and use it: /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -i | grep SSL

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try ad let you know!

Comment: I've installed other php versions but they run on nss package for ssl. I decided to buy another server with centos 6 and lamp, it also uses nss but here I don't get any error, I don't know why

Comment: It's really strange because plesk's php don't know anything about nss, how about to try to carefully remove libcurl nss packages?